# Can I add a row to the middle of a dataset using c#?

Tags: c#, dataset

Is it possible to add a row to the middle of an existing dataset with c#?  I've done a lot of searching and haven't been able to find anything on how to do this.  What have I tried?  I've tried searching a lot and haven't found anything like an 'insertAt' method for datasets.
Thanks
Mike

Comment: Define _middle_. Probably you refer to a `DataTable` inside a `DataSet`.

Comment: Is dataset.Tables[0] a DataTable?  I might be confused.

Comment: Even so, define "middle" for a `DataTable`.

Comment: Anywhere that is not the last or first record.  I will be adding several rows in between other rows in the DataTable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The DataSet consists of a collection of DataTable objects so I assume that you are talking about a Datatable, right? If so, it has an `InsertAt` method:

```
DataTable dt = dataset.Tables[0]; //Get first datatable from dataset
DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
//fill row
dt.Rows.InsertAt(row,3); //Insert at index 3
```

Comment: this is correct as well, I just marked mallan's as the answer because he answered first

Comment: @dmikester1 he didn't, but it's ok ;)

Answer (score 1):

DataSet does not have a rows collection, so you can't add a row to it at all.

You can insert a row by index into a DataTable object using `DataTable.Rows.InsertAt(row, i)`. If the table is in a DataSet, your syntax would be `DataSet.Tables[i].Rows.InsertAt(row, 0)`

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion (though this could take a lot of time), you can create an array or a list array then transfer all the data there from your dataset through for loop or any loop...then put an if statement inside to check where you want to put your extra data like this:

```
List<string> arrayList = dataset;// i know this is not possible just showing you that you have to put all your data from dataset to array:)
List <string> newList = new List<string>();//its up to you if you want to put another temporary array or you could simply output your data from the loop.
//THE LOOP
for(int i = 0; i<=arrayList.Count(); i++){
    if(i == x)//x is the index or you may change this statement its up to you
  {
    //do the print or pass the data to newList
      newList.add(arraList[i]);//not sure about this. its been a while since the last time i use this array list..
  }
}
```

another way is customize your query(if your pulling out some data from database)

happy coding:)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short sample of doing it:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        DataTable dt = ds.Tables.Add("Table");
        dt.Columns.Add("Id");
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[]{i});
        }

        var newRow=dt.NewRow();
        newRow.ItemArray=new string[]{(dt.Rows.Count/2).ToString()+".middle"};
        dt.Rows.InsertAt(newRow, dt.Rows.Count / 2);
    }
}
```